# FFmpeg ignores quantity parameter

Tags: ffmpeg

this is how I use FFmpeg

```sh
ffmpeg -f dshow -i video="UScreenCapture" -vcodec libx264 -q 26 -f flv output.flv
```

the thing is, the quantity is always 28, ffmpeg ignores that. How to fix this? I need a "flash" codec anyway, to stream to twitch tv

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [the documentation](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html), "the meaning of `q` is codec-dependent" and apparently libx264 ignores that option. Use `-crf` (and a `-preset` if you want) instead. The bigger the crf value, the lower the quality.

Answer (score 4):

The options `-q` (and the alias `-qscale`) are ignored by libx264. If you want to
[control the quality](http://ffmpeg.org/trac/ffmpeg/wiki/x264EncodingGuide),
use:

`-crf`

```
ffmpeg -i input -c:v libx264 -crf 22 output.flv
```

Or set the bitrate with `-b:v`

```
ffmpeg -i input -c:v libx264 -b:v 555k output.flv
```

Answer (score 1):

if you wish to generate CQP (constant QP stream), e.g for constant QP=20 i suggest using the following parameters: 
'x264-params qp=20:ipratio=1.0:pbratio=1.0:qpstep=0'

Example:
ffmpeg -s 1920x1080 -i  test.yuv  -vcodec libx264  -x264-params qp=20:ipratio=1.0:pbratio=1.0:qpstep=0 -y test.h264

Notice that 'ipratio=1.0' makes x264 to encode P frame with same QP as I-frame and 'pbratio=1.0' makes x264 to encode B-frame with same QP as P-frame.

Answer (score 0):

The -b options, -q, and -crf seem to do nothing for video qualtiy (at least for my install of ffmpeg version 9), so I am posting a result from another post that gets right to the point

If you want high quality, setting bitrate is a poor way to achieve that. There are many other settings with far bigger influence on quality than bitrate. I would leave the bitrate setting out entirely unless you are having to meet hardware requirements of some sort.

**If you are trying to get higher quality, try something like**

**ffmpeg -i sourcefile.mov -target pal-dvd -qscale 2 -trellis 2 outputfile.mpg**

output video size goes from 13Mb for a 2 min video to 130Mb, but it gets the job done.

Comment: There is no such thing as "ffmpeg version 9".